# Update a Twilio number properties with a dictionary programatically

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-python

I have a Twilio number and a dictionary full of params that I want to set up. The only way I know to set number properties is by passing them into the `number.update()` function, so this is kinda annoying.

If the dictionary keys have the same name as the inputs I'm trying to pass to the update function, is there a cleaner way to do this?

or, can I do better than this?

```
params = {
    'voice_url':'http://endpoint.co',
    'friendly_name':'call a dinosaur'
}

number.update(voice_url=params['voice_url'], friendly_name=params['friendly_name']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To do this you can use the [unpacking operator `**`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) like this:

```py
number.update(**params)
```

`**` unpacks a dictionary into keyword arguments.